# Where is kernel.h?

Tags: c++, linux, include

I'm trying to understand (a little) C++ langage (or C, not sure..).
The working folder is

```
~/ANDROID/lichee/linux-3.4/arch/arm/mach-sun7i
```

In a file named `device.c`, there is this line:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
```

But no linux folder anywhere.
Where is this kernel.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple to find it :

```
find /usr/ -name kernel.h
```

In my linux distro it is : `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h`

Comment: Ah ok, it's in the headers. Thanks a lot